# Is there a tool to extract colors at regular intervals along a curve or line?

Tags: color, software-recommendation

I have an image on which I would like to sample colors. 
It could look like this (it's the Novamind logo) :

[image: Novamindlogo]

I'm looking for a tool that could define a path ( Bézier, circle, regular polygons, for example), set the number of samples I want, and output the colors found along the path in various formats. I' not looking for a Photoshop plug-in, but more something like the DigitalColor Meter on OS X; it's a simple color picker.

Answer (score 1):

There are some great general color analyzers out there but nothing I know of that will perform this kind of specific test. I'm sure you could do it with Illustrator via [Scriptographer](http://scriptographer.org/), if you're ambitious enough ;)

Just for kicks, try out the [Firefox plug-in Rainbow](http://harthur.github.com/rainbow/) and see if you get close to what you're after.